# How can I subset data from a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Let's assume I have the following:

```
df = data.frame(attribute_1 = c(234, 456, 778,  89,  77, 665,  44,  33),
                attribute_2 = c( 9,67,78,777,6, 1, 22, 100))

vec = c(1,44,33,667,77)

subset(df, df$attribute_1 != vec)
```

**how can I exclude the values in *vec* from the *df*?**

The code as it is written here gets an error message

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `!=`, use `%in%` with `!` as `!=` or `==` are elementwise comparison operators which works only when the `lengths` are same or if it is having a length of 1 which gets recycled

```
subset(df, ! attribute_1 %in% vec)
  attribute_1 attribute_2
1         234           9
2         456          67
3         778          78
4          89         777
6         665           1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do

```
subset(df, ! attribute_1 %in% vec)
```

or (using package *tidyverse*)

```
df %>% filter(!attribute_1 %in% vec)
```

or simply

```
df[!df$attribute_1 %in% vec, ]
```